# WooCommerce query quantity on product page

Tags: php, forms, woocommerce

I have a button that I've added to my product page, and I want to query the quantity in the woocommerce_quantity_input() control.  For the life of me I can't find how to do that.  I can get $product information, and $cart information, but I can't find how to get the quantity that is on this page (before I add it to the cart).

```
if ( ! defined( 'ABSPATH' ) ) exit; // Exit if accessed directly

global $woocommerce;
?>

<div class="calculateshipping-button-container" 
    style="display:block;float:<?php echo $button_align_default; ?>;">

    <div class="calculateshipping-button">
        <div class="cs-btn" data-layout="button_count" 
            data-width="<?php echo $option_csbtn_width; ?>" data-show-faces="false">

            <button type="button"  class="shipping-calculator-button button"   
                id="showHideForm"><?php _e('Calculate Shipping', $this->app_name );?>
            </button>
        </div>
     </div>
</div>
<?php 
global $product;
global $quantity;

if(isset($_POST['calc_shipping']) && $_POST['calc_shipping'] == '1')
{
```

so I want to get the quantity next to the "Add To Cart Button"

and is added to the page with:

```
<?php do_action( 'woocommerce_before_shipping_calculator' ); ?>

<form class="shipping_calculator" action="" method="post">
```

with the "Calculate Button" defined as

```
<p><button type="submit" name="calc_shipping" value="1"    class="button_shipping">
<?php _e( 'Calculate', 'woocommerce' ); ?></button></p>
```

Comment: Can you elaborate no what you are trying to do? Or use a screenshot? I don't understand what you are asking.

Comment: Yep.. so I have a button on my product page.  When pressed, I want to query the current count that is in the quanity_input() next to Add to Cart.  I don't want it to add it to the count, I just need that value in a message I need to display.  I do calculations based on the $product, however I can't find where to get the quantity currenly displayed on the page.

Comment: Can you show your code? (Edit the question as code is borderline illegible in the comments). The typical quantity input has a class of `qty` for selection via jquery or a name of `quantity` which then is available as a key in the `$_POST` data.

Comment: Updated the post.  Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I had to add an ajax function to the input field that would then update a hidden field in my form.  Then when the Calculate button is pressed, I have access to the updated quantity.